# How does scala support this sbt DSL syntax?

Tags: scala, sbt

I was looking through the [sbt manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Multiple+subprojects) and I see that you can set projects and infer the location from the name of the val.

`lazy val util = (project in file("util"))`
is equivalent to
`lazy val util = project`
How is this possible?

Comment: Probably a macro or runtime reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [macro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/ab2b39654302ce79aeaf249501abc49a83dafc0e/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Project.scala#L999)

```
/**
 * Creates a new Project.  This is a macro that expects to be assigned directly to a val.
 * The name of the val is used as the project ID and the name of the base directory of the project.
 */
def project: Project = macro Project.projectMacroImpl
```

expands

```
lazy val util = project
```

to

```
Project.apply("util", new File("util"))
```

To see what sbt macros expand to create `project/build.sbt` file with

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ymacro-debug-lite")
```